# dynamic key which contain a concatenation of specific string and iterative integer in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface

I want to declare an interface which will have keys containing specific string values which are the combination of some fixed string and an incremental value e.g. ('first1', 'first2', 'first', 'first4' ).

Here key is the concatenation of fixed string i.e. 'first' and an increment value i.e. (1,2,3,4).

I don't want to use general Object as in my specific case, key should contain some specific string

```
[key: string]: string;
```

e.g.

I want to declare a common interface for both of these objects

Object1

```
{
    'user': admin,
    'login': true,
    'first1': 1,
    'first2': 2,
    'first3': 3;
    'first4': 4;
    'first5': 5;
}
```

Object 2

```
{
    'user': guest,
    'login': false,
    'first1': 1,
    'first2': 2;
    'first3': 3;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you're asking. Please edit your question with a clear explanation and examples.

Comment: @NitzanTomer I have updated it.

Comment: why don't you just remove all those variables and put an array instead? That would simplify everything. What you are trying to do is going to give you some headaches....

Comment: More importantly, why do you want to declare a common interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can write type constraints for *specific* strings:

```
type FirstStrings = "first1" | "first2" | "first3" | "first4";
```

However, it is not possible to constrain a type to be a string that matches a pattern. There is a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) on github about adding support for this.

In the case of index types, it's not even possible to make it a string literal type. You will have to do something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    user: User;
    login: boolean;
    first1?: string;
    first2?: string;
    first3?: string;
    first4?: string;
    first5?: string;
}
```